# How to generate array of text labels for date interval chart programmatically

Tags: java, android, arrays, charts

I'm trying to implement a chart to show some interval based data.

For the orizontal axis labels I need an array that contains all text labels.

The problem is that:

I have to generate this array programmatically according the passed `GregorianCalendar startDate, GregorianCalendar endDate` (and months havent all the same days number)

eg assuming I need a chart from *7th July* to *5 August* like this in the picture

[image]

the needed array of labels must be

```
String labels[]={"lug 7","","","","","","","","lug 14","","","","","","","lug 21","","","","","","","lug 28","","","","ago 4",""}
```

Any help would be most welcome

Comment: thanks for suggestion but I prefer understand how to implement a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to determine the number of days in a month, regardless of leap years etc., as long as your `start`/`endDate` have enough information is to `getMaximum()` like so in this example...

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    // get a calendar instance instantiated with today's date 
    // this would be your start or end date in your program
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();     
    System.out.println(gc.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));     
}
```

> Output: 31

You would then deal with populating the array appropriately based on your requirements and a simple mathematical check.

**EDIT:**

Responding to the comment, here's a simple example using your start and end date in that comment.

```
public static void main(String...args)  {

        GregorianCalendar startDate = 
            new GregorianCalendar(2014, GregorianCalendar.JUNE, 26);
        GregorianCalendar endDate = 
            new GregorianCalendar(2014, GregorianCalendar.OCTOBER, 9);

        while (startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) <= endDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            System.out.println(startDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));  
            startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
    }
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 30
> 31
> 31
> 30
> 31
> ```

You obviously have more to do to handle *any* span, but this shows you this can be done using my suggestion. I'm not really sure what you mean by hard-coding the array. If you're suggesting you'd use an array for the monthly number of days, you could but you'd still have to provide the leap year check.

Comment: thanls, but the problem is to manage correctly periods that include months with different length arbitrarily eg. from 26-06-2014 to 9-10-2014 etc.. I can check month by month and hardcode the array creation, but how to code a solution that works for any interval input?

Comment: That's OK, and possible, with the example above, a little logic, and an additional [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) method or two. I don't have the time to write the solution for you but consider `add`ing months to a `clone`d calendar instance (to preserve the startDate if need be). You have everything you need to produce loops from the month/year values and get each months days.

Comment: @AndreaF, I added an edit that shows grabbing the number of days based on your sample which then of course can be expanded to handle any interval; you'll just have to code the logic for spans of multiple years and so on. I hope I'm understanding you issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I haven't understood if for calendar eg `30-sept-2014` the code `startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);` increase the day and switch automatically to the next month when the current month ends, so I'll have in next iteration `01-oct-2014`, or increase only the month value so the next iteration will be `30-oct-2014`

Comment: @AndreaF, it only adds what you tell it. It will make adjustments to the day iff the day set prior to the add cannot be achieved. IOW, August 31, when adding 1 month, would become September 30. You'd have to clarify your problem for me to help you further. You can add days too, so if you were syncing data with a date you could do it day by day, then it would go from September 30 to October 1.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear, and I should solve my problem. thanks for the help!